# Not able to distribute .aab bundle to google play console from azure pipeline because of certificate issue

Tags: google-play-console

We are trying to build a .aab bundle using azure pipeline since azure doesn't have a task to sign the .aab we are using jarsigner to sign the app. Google app sign in is enabled on the console.

When I try to sign the app using jarsigner getting the below error.

> ##[error]Error: Failed to upload the bundle android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab. Failed with
> message: GaxiosError: The Android App Bundle was signed with multiple
> certificate chains. Please use exactly one.
> at Gaxios._request (/Users/runner/work/_tasks/GooglePlayRelease_8cf7cac0-620b-11e5-b4cf-8565e60f4d27/4.229.0/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:129:23)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async JWT.requestAsync (/Users/runner/work/_tasks/GooglePlayRelease_8cf7cac0-620b-11e5-b4cf-8565e60f4d27/4.229.0/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:368:18)
> {   response: [Object],   config: [Object],   code: 403,   errors:
> [Array]

Since it's complaining of multiple certs I disabled all the signing related tasks on the pipeline and try to publish to console getting the below error.

> ##[error]Error: Failed to upload the bundle android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab. Failed with
> message: GaxiosError: The Android App Bundle was signed with the wrong
> key. Found: SHA1:
> 5E:8F:16:06:2E:A3:CD:2C:4A:0D:54:78:76:BA:A6:F3:8C:AB:F6:25, expected:
> SHA1: 95:11:D2:79:F9:1A:24:2E:FE:41:36:1B:73:4F:53:C5:FF:91:1D:46.
> at Gaxios._request (/Users/runner/work/_tasks/GooglePlayRelease_8cf7cac0-620b-11e5-b4cf-8565e60f4d27/4.229.0/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:129:23)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async JWT.requestAsync (/Users/runner/work/_tasks/GooglePlayRelease_8cf7cac0-620b-11e5-b4cf-8565e60f4d27/4.229.0/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:368:18)
> {   response: [Object],   config: [Object],   code: 403,